# Why does render to texture camera make armature animation freeze in the Game engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, armature, mirror

I needed to make an in-game, realtime mirror, so I set everyhting up as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4KNstJhFeA), including the render-to-texture script. However, when my character is outside the range of the mirror's camera, all armature animations suddenly stop. I've set up a control (cube with simple armature inside), and all other animations seem to work fine, as well as movements. Only the armature animations are frozen when not within the range of the mirror's camera. Please help! [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQ8vTJBeSg8SGhGRDRaeVNpZUU/view?usp=sharing) is the .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "animation culling" build in. This means anything that is not seen by the active camera will not be animated. This is to skip processing time.

This is not always a correct assumption, e.g. when the animation influences physics or as in your case you see it by a different camera.

I know this issue was raised as a bug to allow disabling this sort of culling for certain objects. Just now I do not know the state of that feature.

Comment: Damn. Thanks though. All I managed to do to get around it is to use a Near sensor (instead of the usual Always) to trigger the script controller, which isn't the cleanest fix but oh well.